# Modal image is not appearing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a click event so when an IMG is clicked on a modal will appear with the image in it.

I've tried googling and looking on here but to no avail. maybe I'm just wording it wrong.

```
<div class="modal">
        <div class="modalContent">
          <h2> Full size! </h2>
          <img src="" class="modalImg">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="gallery">
              <img src="img/twilight.jpeg" alt="man in the night" class="showcase">
          </div>

          <div class="list">
            <img src="img/code.jpeg" alt="code on a laptop" class="img1">
            <img src="img/desk.jpeg" alt="desk setup" class="img2">
            <img src="img/iphone.jpeg" alt="Iphone x" class="img3">
            <img src="img/keyboard.jpg" alt="glowing keyboard" class="img4">
            <img src="img/lips.jpg" alt="bloody lips" class="img5">
            <img src="img/crowbar.jpg" alt="man holding crowbar" class="img6">
            <img src="img/horror.jpeg" alt="horror image" class="img7">
            <img src="img/hands.jpeg" alt="bloody hands" class="img8">
          </div>
```

```
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const img = document.querySelector('.img1');
const myImg = document.querySelector('.modalImg');
img.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  myImg.src = this.src;
});


I'm just attempting to have this work on the first image now, So i'm hoping to make is so on click the image shows in a pop modal. now the modal shows up just fine and has the h2 set but nothing shows up aside from that.
```

Comment: so I can get this to work properly if i use the const I created "img" but not with "this" am I using it in the wrong context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function from arrow function to normal function then will work.

```
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const img = document.querySelector('.img1');
const myImg = document.querySelector('.modalImg');
-- img.addEventListener('click', () => {
++ img.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  myImg.src = this.src;
});
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), An arrow function does not have its own this, it follow the normal variable lookup rules. So if you need to get the image.src,  you need to using the function key word instead of arrow function.

Comment: Awesome thank you so if I understand "This" does not work with arrow functions?

Comment: I know this might be asking a lot I would like to apply this same effect to each individual IMG without creating a new function and "const" for each img is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: no where you are using `this` then how come it matters?

Comment: @brandon.b You need to use `document.querySelector` to select all the images. The images should be in a nodeList(Array like Object), and you need to use `forEach` to add event on each individual IMG.

Comment: @brk The callback function of the `addEventListener` has use `this`. The OP try to use this.src to get the image source when image clicked.